# Css with flexbox wrap text

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm building a forum with `flexbox`. But I've got a problem. How do I wrap the text from a column to a new line?

Here is my example simulated:

https://jsbin.com/bijikimubu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Also somewhere else on my site:

[image]

--EDIT--

With `word-break: break-all;` it looks like this in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `word-break: break-all` on the `p` containing the text?

Comment: Yes but in IE it looks very weird after I add more lines. I will add a screenshot above.

Comment: @jamie you know that this happens because there are no spaces or `-` in the text right ? Are you expecting that long text without spaces ?

Comment: can you add a snapshot of how its behavior should be

Comment: Is the IE 11 appearance what you want for other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

check this

```css
footer {
 background: #f00;
}

margin-top auto,
.Footer__body {
 height: 70px;
}

.Footer__bar {
 height: 10px;
}

.Container {
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100vh;
}

ul.Navigation__body {
 padding-left: 0;
}

ul {
 margin: 0px;
}

.Navigation__top {
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #fde428;
 height: 10px;
}

.Navigation__body {
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: #002e5b;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.Navigation__item {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 justify-content: center;
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 flex: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/* Main section */
.Center {
 display: flex;
 
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.Row {
 display: flex;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
}

.Forum {
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: #fff;
 height: 375;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.Forum__body {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 flex-direction: column;
 min-width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 35%;
}

.Forum__item__body {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.Forum__item__body_content p{
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Container">
    <header>
        <div class="Navigation">
            <div class="Navigation__top"></div>
            <nav v-show="authenticated">
                <ul class="Navigation__body">
                    <li class="Navigation__item" v-link="{ name: 'Forums' }">
                        <p>Home</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="Navigation__item" v-link="{ name: 'EditProfile', params: { user: user.slug }}">
                        <p>Profiel</p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="Navigation__item" v-link="{ name: 'Subscription' }">
                        <p>Abonnementen</p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="Navigation__item" v-link="{ name: 'Corporations' }">
                        <p>Corporaties</p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="Navigation__item" v-link="{ name: 'Users' }">
                        <p>Gebruikers</p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="Navigation__item" @click="destroyLogin">
                        <p>Uitloggen</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
    <div class="Row Center">
  <div class="Forum ">
      <p class="Forum__title">Name</p>
     <div class="Forum__item__body_content">
      <p>DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription
            DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription
            DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription
            DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    

  <div class="Loader" v-if="loading">
   <grid-loader :loading="loading" :color="color" :size="size"></grid-loader>
  </div>
  
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="Footer">
            <div class="Footer__body">
                <p>© Company</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Footer__bar"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed your markup a bit and css too

Hope this helps

PS:This styles are in css